# Lines in a windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, line

Just a simple question: I'm developing a Windows store app and for one function I want to show an intercept theorm. For that (now my question) I need some lines. Do I need to create an Image or is there any other possibility to display simple lines on a XAML-Form (I'm using XAML and C#).
I'm coming from Windows forms and there I used a line control from the Toolbox, but I can't find anything like that in the Toolbox of VS for Windows 8. I also had the idea to use GDI, but I read that it doesn't exist any longer (am I wrong?).

Comment: You are correct. GDI is not available in Windows Store apps. While that worked for Windows Forms, graphic engines have moved on.

Answer (score 1):

You should draw *shape* elements, in your XAML (or code-behind).

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465055.aspx

Comment: <Line Stroke="White" Width="5" X1="100" Y1="100" X2="200" Y2="500" Grid.Row="1"/>
But after some seconds, it disappears.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like bellow

```
 <Line X1="0" Y1="0" X2="100" Y2="100" Stroke="Red"></Line>
```

this draws a line from (0,0) to (100,100).

don't forget to use stroke otherwise it won't be displayed.